# jquery on click function not displaying

Tags: jquery

I am having two buttons. On click on any button it must show which button i have clicked. But my code is not working. when i click the button the respective id of the button is to be displayed. I didnt understand where the mistake is. Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn").click(function(){

 var qn=$(this).attr("id");  
 ("#two").html.("you clicked on button"+qn);  

 });   

});
</script>
<style>
#one
{
  width:100%;
  height:70px; 
  background-color:green;
  clear:both;
}
#two
{
  width:75%;
  height:250px; 
  overflow-y:scroll;
  float:left;  
}
#three
{
  width:24.5%;
  height:50px;  
  float:right;  
  float:right;   
}
.btn
{
  width:45px;
  height:45px;
  align-text:center;  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three">
   <?php
     $i=1;
     for($i=1;$i<3;$i++)
     {
         echo"<button class='btn' id='$i' value='$i'>$i</button>";
     }
   ?>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: your buttons don't have the class .btn. jQuery selector returns nothing

Comment: you have a type error `("#two").html.()` it should be `$("#two").html()`

Comment: Sometimes small mistakes may lead to big headache. Its working thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
$("#two").html("you clicked on button"+qn);
```

And not

```
("#two").html.("you clicked on button"+qn);
```

And secondly place your JavaScript under your code is much preferable

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".btn").click(function(){

 var qn=$(this).attr("id");  
 $("#two").html("you clicked on button"+qn);  

 });   

});
</script>
```

first you missing jQuery symbol `$` and add a extra `.` after `html` function

Answer (score 0):

You did typo near `html.()` and also missed the `$` with `("#two").` in your script. It should be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        var qn=$(this).attr("id");  
        $("#two").html("you clicked on button"+qn);  
    });   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. It's working.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".btn").click(function(){
      var qn=$(this).attr("id"); 
  alert(qn)  
 });
});
</script>
<style>
#one
{
  width:100%;
  height:70px; 
  background-color:green;
  clear:both;
}
#two
{
  width:75%;
  height:250px; 
  overflow-y:scroll;
  float:left;  
}
#three
{
  width:24.5%;
  height:50px;  
  float:right;  
  float:right;   
}
.btn
{
  width:45px;
  height:45px;
  align-text:center;  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three">
  <button class='btn' id='1' value='1'>1</button>
  <button class='btn' id='2' value='1'>2</button>
  <button class='btn' id='3' value='1'>3</button>
     
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Just replace my code with your for loop inside PHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code.

It should be

```
html(), not html.().
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3zhw5hja/